# How to grep output of ls -lhR / for particular owner (ex. root)?

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash

Is there anyway I can list all the files that belong to a particular owner?

Additionally can I list all the files that belong to a group?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/find.1.html) should answer:

```
sudo find / -user root
```

To search a specific directory, just replace `/` with the full path. You can drop the `sudo` part of the command if you don't mind warnings about being unable to read special files.

For group ownership finds, use:

```
sudo find / -group root
```

Comment: I was going to suggest some hackery using cut and grep, but this is much cleaner.